# group rows based on column and sum their values

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1':['Ax','Bx','Ay','By'], 'c2':[1,2,3,4]})

   c1  c2
0  Ax  1
1  Bx  2
2  Ay  3
3  By  4
```

I'd like to group `x`s and `y`s in `c1` and sum their respective `c2` values.

Desired output:

```
   c1  c2
0  Cx  3
1  Cy  7
```

Comment: Why does `Ax` + `Bx` equal `Cx`? how can you sum the `c1` column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

example

```
df.groupby(df['c1'].str[-1]).sum()
```

output:

```
    c2
c1  
x   3
y   7
```

use following code:

```
df.groupby('C' + df['c1'].str[-1]).sum().reset_index()
```

result:

```
    c1  c2
0   Cx  3
1   Cy  7
```

Answer (score 1):

You may do:

```
out = df.groupby(df.c1.str[-1]).sum().reset_index()
out['c1'] = 'C' + out['c1']
```

print(out):

```
   c1  c2
0  Cx   3
1  Cy   7
```

Answer (score 1):

Groupby is very flexible so let's group by the last character of the "c1" column and then sum the "c2" values:

```py
>>> (df.groupby(df.c1.str[-1])["c2"]
       .sum().reset_index()
       .assign(c1=lambda fr: fr.c1.radd("C")))

   c1  c2
0  Cx   3
1  Cy   7
```

Without the `assign` at the end, resultant "c1" values are the groupers, i.e., "x" and "y". I add (from right, hence `radd`) the character "C" to them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposition using [`pandas.Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) with [`GroupBy.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) :

```
out = (
        df
          .assign(c1= df["c1"].str.replace("[A-Z]", "C", regex=True))
          .groupby("c1", as_index=False).sum(numeric_only=True)
       )
```

Output :

```
​
print(out)
​
   c1  c2
0  Cx   3
1  Cy   7
```