# Python: How to ffill and bfill a column with nan?

Tags: python, pandas

How might I ffill and bfill a column that contains nans?

Consider this example:

```
# data
df = pd.DataFrame([
            [np.nan, '2019-01-01', 'P', 'O', 'A'],
            [np.nan, '2019-01-02', 'O', 'O', 'A'],
            ['A', '2019-01-03', 'O', 'O', 'A'],
            ['A', '2019-01-04', 'O', 'P', 'A'],
            [np.nan, '2019-01-05', 'O', 'P', 'A'],
            [np.nan, '2019-01-01', 'P', 'O', 'B'],
            ['B', '2019-01-02', 'O', 'O', 'B'],
            ['B', '2019-01-03', 'O', 'O', 'B'],
            ['B', '2019-01-04', 'O', 'P', 'B'],
            [np.nan, '2019-01-05', 'O', 'P', 'B'],
            ], columns=['ID', 'Time', 'FromState', 'ToState', 'Expected'])

# updated try
df['ID'] = df['ID'].transform(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill() )
```

Comment: `df.groupby(['ID', 'Time']` If you include ID in your groupby columns, then the NaN values will end up in their own groups, without any non-NaN values to fill from. Is there a reason you need the groupby?

Comment: need desired output

Comment: @PandaKim `Expected` has been included since posting.

Comment: i don think so. i can see only your try. make desired output like this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74644651/group-rows-based-on-column-and-sum-their-values

Comment: @JohnStud Why is row six expected to be B? Shouldn't it be A, since a previous row has A?

Comment: df['ID'] = df['ID'].ffill().bfill(). If eg FromState column had a NaN then just do df['FromState'] = df['FromState'].ffill().bfill()

Comment: @NickODell It should be an even time series, thus, A has five rows, B has five rows.

Comment: @JohnStud You should put that in the question. :) It's very much not clear from the text of the question that you care about that.

Comment: it will be solved in 5 minutes if you make desired output. I don't know why answerer  ask to you several questions to solve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```py
df['ID'] = df['ID'].ffill(limit=1).bfill(limit=2)
```